# Continuity and composition

Tags: general-topology

Let $A \subset X$, where $X$ is a topological space and $\iota_A :A \to X$ the inclusion map. Let now also $Y$ be a topological space.

I wanna show that $f:Y \to A$ is continuous iff $\iota_A \circ f: Y \to X$ is continuous.

Well one side is easy: If $f$ is continuous, so also $\iota_A \circ f$ is continuous as a composition of continuous function. But I can't proof the other one.

Answer (score 1):

An open set of $A$ is the intersection of $A$ and an open set of $X$. Let $U$ be open in $X$, one has
\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(A\cap U) = (\iota_A \circ f)^{-1}(U)
\end{equation}
whence the equivalence.